# Get the html that makes up an element reference?

Tags: jquery, html

Does anybody know, if i have an object like `$('#input')` how can I get the html that would make it up, like `<input id="input" />` as a text string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of the `outerHTML` plugins, [like this](http://dbj.org/dbj/?p=91) will work:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
  return jQuery('<div />').append(this.clone()).html();
}
```

Then just call it, e.g.:

```
var html = $("#input").outerHTML();
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/R6Gkh/), all of those plugins use basically the same concept, clone it, stick it in a container, get the innerHTML of that container.